# Unexpected output in bash script. Instead of the literal "?", there is echoed "d" and "i"

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, grep, ps

I have the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "PS to AWK"

read prg

check=($(ps -e | grep $prg | awk '{print "kILL " $4" "$1 " ? [y/n]"}'))

echo "${check[@]}"
```

The assumed output should be:

```
PS to AWK
auda
kILL audacious 2423 ? [y/n]
```

But unfortunately my output looks like this:

```
PS to AWK
auda
kILL audacious 2423 d i [y/n]
```

Someone has a hint why the question mark is lost and where the "d" and "i" are resulting from?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why are you populating array `check`?

Comment: Because for later use.

Comment: @tripleee: Sorry I had to reopen this because that duplicate marked answer doesn't really answer this problem.

Comment: There are different pitfalls If I quote or not, even if I use extra spaces or not. There right answer below solves my problem, the suggested answer does not. The big hint is `check < <(...)` and I can use my quotation without any problems, as I always do. I think it is more direction-related.

Comment: Why don't you use `pgrep auda` ? `tokill=$(pgrep $prg);cmdname=$(ps ho cmd $tokill);read -p "Kill: $cmdname: $tokill"  ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of populating your shell array `check` using output from command substitution (which is subjected to glob expansion and word spitting) you should use `read` with process substitution like this:

```
read -ra check < <(ps -e | awk -v p="$prg" '$0 ~ p{print "kILL " $4" "$1 " ? [y/n]"}')
```

Then examine the result using:

```
echo "${check[@]}"

# or
declare -p check
```

Comment: anubhava: Thank you, this works perfect for me, and checking an array with `declare` is really very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

The unquoted `?` is expanded as a wildcard by the shell. You have two files with single-character names in the current directory.

The fix is to generally quote everything, unless you specifically require the shell to perform wildcard expansion and whitespace tokenization on a value.

The wildcard gets expanded in the array assignment, so you could quote that:

```
check=("$(ps -e | awk -v prg="$prg" '$0 ~ prg {print "kILL " $4" "$1 " ? [y/n]"}')")
```

but then you might was well not use an array.  But then you might as well just capture the PID.

```
pid=$(ps -e | awk -v prg="$prg" '$0 ~ prg { print $1 }')
```

This loses the process name, though. You could refactor the script to print just the machine-readable parts, and then use those in a print statement.

```
check=($(ps -e | awk -v prg="$prg" '$0 ~ prg { print $1, $4 }'))
read -p "kILL ${check[1]} ${check[0]}? [y/n]"
```

(Incidentally, aligning the question mark with the previous word, as is the convention in English orthography, would also fix your problem, though sort of accidentally.  Notice also how to avoid the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) in the examples above.)

Comment: If I quote the question mark like this `check=($(ps -e | grep $prg | awk '{print "kILL " $4" "$1 " \? [y/n]"}'))` I only get an additional warning and there is still no `?`in my output.

Comment: Awk processes and removes the backslash so it's no longer there by the time the shell evaluates the output from Awk. I would just print the PID from Awk and defer the string formatting to the final `echo` (or perhaps `read -p` if you are going to be reading user input anyway).